# Global Variable in Drools stateless session

Tags: drools, rule-engine

How global variables are set for drools  stateless session.

Lets say two threads access same session but sets a global variable customer arraylist with 
new arraylist for each thread. Does second thread's arraylist replaces first thread's arraylist for global variable customer.

That seems the case from StatelessKnowledgeSession class documentation :

StatelessKnowledgeSessions support globals, scoped in a number of ways. I'll cover the non-command way first, as commands are scoped to a specific execution call. Globals can be resolved in three ways. The StatelessKnowledgeSession supports getGlobals(), which returns a Globals instance. These globals are shared for ALL execution calls, so be especially careful of mutable globals in these cases - as often execution calls can be executing simultaneously in different threads. Globals also supports a delegate, which adds a second way of resolving globals. Calling of setGlobal(String, Object) will actually be set on an internal Collection, identifiers in this internal Collection will have priority over supplied delegate, if one is added. If an identifier cannot be found in the internal Collection, it will then check the delegate Globals, if one has been set.

http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.1/javadocs/org/drools/runtime/StatelessKnowledgeSession.html

Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot give you a fully reliable answer (because I haven't tested this), I would say that you are right because

1. under the `StatelessKnowledgeSession`'s hood, Drools uses a `StatefulKnowledgeSession` and in a stateful session, I would expect that the call of `setGlobal(...)` overrides the value from a previous call.
2. Globals are held in a "globals store"; this globals store is session-specific, which means that if you achieve to simultaneously access the same session using different threads, one thread will override the globals store of the other - whichever thread's `setGlobal(...)` is executed last.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm- globals are stored in shared memory between threads.

We were using a global to store the result from each execution and found that when multiple threads were executing at the same time, we would occasionally get the wrong result because another thread jumped in and overwrote the global before the previous thread had retrieved the value.